# SQL - Get unique values by key selected by condition

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, union

I want to clean a dataset because there are repeated keys that should not be there. Although the key is repeated, other fields do change. On repetition, I want to keep those entries whose `country` field is not null. Let's see it with a simplified example:

```
|  email  | country |
| 1@x.com |  null   |
| 1@x.com |   PT    |
| 2@x.com |   SP    |
| 2@x.com |   PT    |
| 3@x.com |  null   |
| 3@x.com |  null   |
| 4@x.com |   UK    |
| 5@x.com |  null   |
```

Email acts as key, and country is the field which I want to filter by. On email repetition:

1. Retrieve the entry whose country is not null (case 1)
2. If there are several entries whose country is not null, retrieve one of them, the first occurrence for simplicity (case 2)
3. If all the entries' country is null, again, retrieve only one of them (case 3)
4. If the entry key is not repeated, just retrieve it no matter what its country is (case 4 and 5)

The expected output should be:

```
|  email  | country |
| 1@x.com |   PT    |
| 2@x.com |   SP    |
| 3@x.com |  null   |
| 4@x.com |   UK    |
| 5@x.com |  null   |
```

I have thought of doing a UNION or some type of JOIN to achieve this. One possibility could be querying:

```
SELECT
...
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
   WHERE country IS NOT NULL
) AS a
...
```

and then match it with the full table to add those values which are missing, but I am not able to imagine the way since my experience with SQL is limited.

Also, I have read about the [COALESCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce) function and I think it could be helpful for the task.

Comment: is there a primary key like id or something ?

Comment: There is no such thing as *first occurrence* without a column that defines the order of the rows.

Comment: @forpas can't we use something like `row_number` ?

Comment: row_number without an ORDER BY clause may return arbitrary results.

Comment: There is not any primary key or ID. The email should be unique, but as I have no control over the ingestion and update of the table, I can not guarantee that. That's why I am trying to find a query which gives me those unique email entries, with the condition of prioritizing those which has a country value. If it helps, the table is not that big, there are like 500k entries, so I can perform complex operations (although simpler solution is prefered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by email order by country nulls last) = 1
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Could you please explain the role `QUALIFY`, `ROW_NUMBER()` and `OVER()` perform on the query?

Comment: [qualify](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) filters only rows which match the criteria. [row_number](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number) returns the sequential row ordinal (1-based) of each row for each ordered partition. [over](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_over_clause) clause references a window that defines a group of rows in a table upon which to use an analytic function